# Isn't every language regular, according to formal definition of it?

Tags: regular-language

This is the definition of regular languages from [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language):

> The collection of regular languages over an alphabet `Σ` is defined recursively as follows:
>
> - The empty language `Ø` is a regular language.
> - For each `a ∈ Σ` (a belongs to Σ), the singleton language `{a}` is a regular language.
> - If `A` and `B` are regular languages, then `A ∪ B` (union), `A • B` (concatenation), and `A*` (Kleene star) are regular languages.
> - No other languages over `Σ` are regular.

Now think about `aⁿbⁿ` which we know is not regular, but doesn't it pass the above  rules?

`{a}` is regular, so is `{b}` and also their concatenation and thus the mentioned lang!

it feels like I'm mistaking set of languages which is, in other words, set of sets; for set of words which is, the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken in your statement that you can form this specific language from the rules. Formally, this follows from the [Pumping Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). To address the reasoning in your question, though:

- *{a}* is regular, so by repeated concatenation, *{a^m}* is regular
- *{b}* is regular, so by repeated concatenation, *{b^n}* is regular

so their concatenation, which is anything of the form *{a^m b^n}* is regular as well, but it is precisely the constraint *m == n* that you cannot formulate via this family.

Answer (score 1):

`aⁿbⁿ` is a language that contains **only** the strings with `n`x `a`s followed by `n`x`b`s.

You can create a regular language that is a superset of this language, but not this language itself.

Answer (score -1):

You're right, `{a}` is regular and `{b}` is regular. Thus, by the rules you mentioned, their concatenation is regular as well. However, the concatenation of two languages is defined as `{vw | v in L_1, w in L_2}`. Since both `L_1` and `L_2` only contain a single word (`a` and `b`, respectively), this definition is equivalent to `{vw | v = a, w = b}`, which is the set `{ab}`.

Thus, the concatenation of the two languages is the set `{ab}`, not `a^n b^n`.